# Returning values from Asynctask

Tags: java, android

Okay I have been trying to get this to work for some time now. I want to be able to have my user login without having the UI hang until the server responds. When the doinbackground is complete I want it to pass an int value or perhaps a boolean value to the postexecute and then the rest of my code will execute. For some reason I have having problems passing values.

Would anyone be able to help me?

```
private class login extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>{
    ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Loading, Please wait...", true);
    String user = "";
    @Override
    protected int doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("thread", "Doing Something...");
        int val = 0;
        if(db.userLogin(userTxt.getText().toString(), passTxt.getText().toString(), getApplicationContext()) == "No User Found, please try again!"){
            val = 0;
        }
        return val;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute(){
        //dialog.dismiss();
        Log.i("thread", "Started...");
        dialog.show();
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(int result){
        Log.i("thread", "Done...");
        dialog.dismiss();
        if(result == 0){
            toast.setText("No User Found, please try again!");
            toast.show();
        }else{
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(ctx, userInfo.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("user", user);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please explain what your "problems passing values" are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `AsyncTask` you supply 3 types.
The first one is used to pass parameters to the background thread,
the second one is used to pass information when publishing progress, and the third one is used to return information from the background thread to `onPostExecute`.

You are currently using the first type only.

try:

```
private class login extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Integer>{
```

and then

```
protected void onPostExecute(Integer result){
```

For more information, see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) at the section "AsyncTask's generic types".

Comment: Thank you for you quick response. I was having a hard time understanding that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your login class to accept an int or boolean in the postExecute(Result) method, you must specify in the AsyncTask's generic types what type of value to pass in.

So, if you would like an int to be passed in, you will need to define your class something like this: `private class login extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Integer>`
and a boolean would look like this: `private class login extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Boolean>`

Please note that these are the Objects, Integer and Boolean, rather than the primitives, int and boolean.  You should have no issue returning an int or boolean from your doInBackground method(Integer...), as autoboxing should take care of the conversion.